# Lib Gdx json serializationexception and missing no-arg constructor

Tags: java, serialization, libgdx, filehandle

When trying to execute this piece of code:

```
public void load(String filename) { 
   FileHandle file = Gdx.files.external(filename + ".bim");
   Json json = new Json();      
   String text = file.readString();
   datamap.clear(); 
   datamap = json.fromJson(HashMap.class, text);
```

I get an error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot be created
>   (missing no-arg constructor): com.bvo.easyBim.Model.Cursor    at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
>   Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot
>   be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.bvo.easyBim.Model.Cursor
>     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.newInstance(Json.java:915)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:793)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:803)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:644)   at
>   com.bvo.easyBim.View.DataProcessor.load(DataProcessor.java:85)    at
>   com.bvo.easyBim.View.World.init(World.java:115)   at
>   com.bvo.easyBim.View.WorldRenderer.buttons(WorldRenderer.java:173)    at
>   com.bvo.easyBim.View.WorldRenderer.render(WorldRenderer.java:106)     at
>   com.bvo.easyBim.Screens.AppScreen.render(AppScreen.java:22)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)    at
>   com.bvo.easyBim.EasyBim.render(EasyBim.java:39)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:187)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   com.bvo.easyBim.Model.Cursor  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.newInstance(Json.java:901)    ... 12 more

I am trying to translate the json file back into the datamap after It was correctly saved in another piece of code. ( A hashmap ) but this does not seem to work .

I am guessing that he is unable to read the text string, but I actually have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception message "Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.bvo.easyBim.Model.Cursor" describes exactly what is going wrong.

The Libgdx JSON code uses reflection to create instances of objects and initialize them.  In your example, there must be a `com.bvo.easyBim.Model.Cursor` in the saved JSON file.  So when reading that file, the JSON code needs to create an instance of a `Cursor` to put the data in.  It assumes there is a no-argument constructor that it can use to create an empty `Cursor` (it cannot figure out which constructor would be appropriate otherwise).  However, it seems that there is no such method.

You will either have to add a no-argument constructor to `Cursor`, or you will have to add a custom serializer (see https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/JsonParsing#Customizing_serialization) that knows how to save a `Cursor` instance and knows the appropriate constructor to invoke when reading a `Cursor` back in.