# Libgdx Load/save array in Json

Tags: arrays, json, libgdx

I want to save an array of `Mission.class` which have variables as follows:

```
public class Mission {

public MissionEnum missionEnum;
public int progress;

public Mission(MissionEnum missionEnum, int progress) {
    this.missionEnum = missionEnum;
    this.progress = progress;
}
```

and also save missions in another java class:

```
public void saveMissions() {
    Json json = new Json();
    json.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
    json.addClassTag("Mission", Mission.class);
    FileHandle missionFile = Gdx.files.local("missions_array.json");
    missionFile.writeString(json.prettyPrint(missions), false);
}
```

and load missions:

```
public void loadMissions() {
    if (Gdx.files.local("missions_array.json").exists()) {
        try {
            FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("missions_array.json");
            Json json = new Json();
            json.addClassTag("Mission", Mission.class);
            missions = json.fromJson(Array.class, Mission.class, file);
            for (Mission mission : missions) {
                Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Mission loaded: " + mission.missionEnum);
            }
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Load missions successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.error(TAG, "Unable to read Missions: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I got json like this:

```
[
{
"class": "Mission",
"missionEnum": "BUY_POWERUP"
},
{
"class": "Mission",
"missionEnum": "DISTANCE_ONE_RUN_2"
},
{
"class": "Mission",
"missionEnum": "BANANA_TOTAL_2",
"progress": 35
}
]
```

However when `loadMissions()` is run I got the `"Load missions successful"` log shown but `"Mission loaded..."` aren't shown without any error log.  Missions appeared not loaded properly. I do not know what went wrong because another array is loaded successful the same way.

Comment: Is it possible that the missing progress field in some missions creates the issue? What error logs are shown? Perhaps adding a constructor with only a Mission Enum and setting the progress to zero solves it.

Comment: I have reverted back to preferences. nvm

Answer (score 1):

**Updated response:**

Add an empty contructor and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15283446/1009132) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507466/invoke-object-constructor-when-deserializing-json-using-libgdx)

> You will either have to add a no-argument constructor to (Mission), or
>   you will have to add a custom serializer (see
>   https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/JsonParsing#Customizing_serialization)
>   that knows how to save a (Mission) instance and knows the appropriate
>   constructor to invoke when reading a (Mission) back in.

```
public Mission() {
    // Do nothing.
}
```

[Reading & writing JSON](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-and-writing-JSON)

> The class implementing Json.Serializable must have a zero argument
>   constructor because object construction is done for you.

Alternatively delete the unused constructor. I think Enigo answer is also correct so I'm going to upvote his answer.

[Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you
>   must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a
>   no-argument, default constructor for any class **without constructors.**
>   This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the
>   superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the
>   superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify
>   that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an
>   implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument
>   constructor.

**Note:** I didn't test our responses,  I have not developed games or used libgdx in the last two years.

Also read this libgdx issue: [Json - constructor default value with Enum](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/743):

> I don't know if this would be called a bug but, I have a case where I
>   have an enum like this;
>
> Then I have a class with 2 constructors;
>
> This second gets called by my framework, the first by Json
>   deserialization.
>
> ...

**Previous response:**

I guess that the missing progress field in some Mission classes can be the source of the issue but would be interesting to read the error logs to be sure.

I followed [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON), [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-) and [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.java#L786) to confirm this but it's hard without extra information about the exact log error.

Comment: no, actually the absent fields are not the source of a problem. they are initialized with default values - zeros in case of `int`

Comment: In that case, try Enigo response, he reproduced your issue and seems that found the issue.

Comment: they are int with zero value.  The ones have values aren't loaded either.

Comment: Mission had no arg constructor.

Comment: Your question doesn't reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why there are no errors in the logs, since while reproducing your problem I've got an exception.

The problem is in `loadMissions()` method: you create new Json parser without setting the class tag:

```
Json json = new Json();
// add the line below
json.addClassTag("Mission", Mission.class);
missions = json.fromJson(Array.class, Mission.class, file);
....
```

Without the tag parser doesn't know what is `"class": "Mission"` in json file.

**Update**

Another thing that may cause this issue is the args-constructor. At least, when I added it I got an exception. If you don't use it - just delete.
Still, quite weird that you don't have any exceptions in logs'cos I definitely have.

Comment: Actually I didn't use addClassTag also for saveMission but I still get the same problem.  Just didn't want to show the package yet.  Thank now I know I need addClassTag in both method.  It doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: I added class tag to the question